# Get a page's average number of posts / day using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate a Facebook page's average number of posts per day using the API. The problem is that the API does not show when the page was created. Instead, I'm downloading all the posts and using the oldest post as some sort of creation date (which is not 100 percent correct...).

The problem is when a page adds backdated posts. For instance, someone might post a picture in 2012 that's dated 2008. Then that post will be oldest, even if the page hasn't existed that long.

One solution is to go by the updated_time field instead of created_time, but it's not a great solution that still may not be correct.

Is there someway to get around this?

Sorry if this question has come up before, but I couldn't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're looking for isn't possible using the API.

For a given post two dates are returned - created_time and updated_time.

As you rightly pointed out the created_time can be updated to add a post in the past. 
updated_time also will not work for you as this gets updated whenever someone comments on a post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post

Comment: I find both Facebook's and Twitter's API lacking in several ways, this being one. Too bad. But thank you for your answer.